# What's the purpose of initializing a variable to its default value?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

All over our codebase, I see stuff like this all the time:

```
 private bool myBool1 = false;
 private bool myBool2 = false;
```

What's the point of creating a variable and setting its value to the default, instead of simply just `private bool myBool1;`?

I have billions of notifications from Resharper saying its redundant :)

Comment: You'll have to consult your teams code guidelines :) (more than likely some members of your team have come from languages such as c)

Comment: I know it's pointless but I've always done this just out of habit. I'm sure many teams have guidelines that require this too. I think it just comes down to preference.

Comment: You can configure Resharper not to display this specific message. Usually such code appears because of habits or to strictly specify that it is initialized to "false" in order not to confuse anybody not too familiar with C# specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the purpose of initializing a variable to its default value?

Nothing, it might be just a practice. It can be clear to newbie who don't know the default value of `bool`(Of course, he can't be a developer if he doesn't know this).

While resharper is right in saying it is redundant it was even harmful in [earlier version of .Net](http://blog.codinghorror.com/for-best-results-dont-initialize-variables/) though it is optimized later.

After reading this article only I myself stopped initializing fields to its default value.

Comment: Thanks for the article, will mark yours as the answer as that provides some hard evidence on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessarily to do it that way, but rather a "code" policy that is maintained within a production environment. It is explicit that myBool1 is false as default, but it may be considered as a good habit (good as in consequent) to declare your variables to their default values manually.

Try to be consequent in what you are doing in your production environment. If you'd like to be clear and declare all variables to their default values manually, you should - in my opinion - do it everywhere. However, morally I think that manually declaring your variables to their default values is a bad habit, because it only gives your compiler more work to do and it is self-evident that that should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: "considered a good habit" is an opinion. I personally see it as the opposite because it just makes more work for the compiler

Comment: It is. Actually, I ment that it can be considered as a good habit within a production environment, so it depends on what is consequently done.